# Visual Studio 2013 not thrown user-unhandled exceptions

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, first-chance-exception

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(null);
    MessageBox.Show("hnjkh");
}
```

When I run above sample code, VS2013 says A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. Then remaining code not work.

Is this behaviour normal?

If this behaviour is normal, when a first chance exception occured, sometimes I can not find location of the problem. Debugging in this way is very hard for large projects.

How can i find exact line of the problematic code?

I don't want to toggle exceptions for every type of exception. Also when I toggle exceptions then it is thrown even user handled. I want to show only user unhandled exceptions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VS2010 does not show unhandled exception message in a WinForms Application on a 64-bit version of Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933958/vs2010-does-not-show-unhandled-exception-message-in-a-winforms-application-on-a)

Comment: Yes i think the problem is related Form_Load event. When i move codes to button1_click then it is working normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933958/vs2010-does-not-show-unhandled-exception-message-in-a-winforms-application-on-a). When i move codes to button1_click then it works normally. Thanks to Hans Passant.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the Exceptions thrown for Common Language Runtime Exceptions

Debug->Exceptions
Select the thrown check box next to "Common Language Runtime Exceptions"

Comment: I don't want to toggle exceptions for every type of exception. Also when I toggle exceptions then it is thrown even user handled. I want to show only user unhandled exceptions.